# How do I access a vector within a class function?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, vector

I am currently trying to create an Open Addressed Hash Table however I appear to be having trouble accessing a vector from one class function and the vector is created in another class function.

I am having trouble passing two variables to a function really. I want to access the vector created in the constructor, from the insertion function.

The error message we receive is:

```
 OAHashVector was no declared in this scope. OAHashVector.insert(addElement, hashvalue);
```

It's this line that is causing the errors:

```
 OAHashVector.insert(addElement, hashvalue);
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::string type;

template <class T>
class openhash {
private:  
    T addElement;
    T deleteElement;
    T searchElement;
    T input_element;

public:
    void initilisation();
    void delete_element();
    void lookup_element();
    void insert_element(openhash<T>);
    void size_table();
    void print_table();
    T HashKeyCalc(T input_element, string element_type){   // function takes in string and returns hash value

        int hashKey;
        /*if (element_type == "string"){
            int i = 0;
            while (i < input_element.size()){
                hashKey = hashKey + input_element.at(i);
                i++;
            }

            hashKey = hashKey%100;
        } else*/ if (element_type == "int"){
            hashKey = input_element;
            hashKey = hashKey%100;
        } /*else if (element_type == "char"){
            hashKey = input_element;
            hashKey = hashKey%100;
        } else if (element_type == "double"){
            for(int i = 0; i <17; i++){
                input_element = input_element*10;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j <17; j++){
                input_element = input_element%10;
            }
            hashKey = input_element;
        } else if (element_type == "float"){
            for(int i = 0; i <7; i++){
                input_element = input_element*10;
            }
            for(int j = 0; j <7; j++){
                input_element = input_element%10;
            }
            hashKey = input_element;
        }*/




        cin.clear(); // clears input buffer
        input_element;

        return hashKey;

    }
    openhash();
    ~openhash();

};



    template <class T>
    void openhash<T>::initilisation(){
        cout << "iii";
    }
    template <class T>
    void openhash<T>::delete_element(){
        cout << "iii";
    }
    template <class T>
    void openhash<T>::lookup_element(){
        cout << "iii";
    }

    template <class T>
    void openhash<T>::insert_element(openhash<T> OAHash){
        cout << "Please enter the element you would like to add: ";

        cin >> addElement; //takes in element user wishes to add

        int hashvalue = OAHash.HashKeyCalc(addElement, type);
        **OAHashVector.insert(addElement, hashvalue);**

    }


    template <class T>
    void openhash<T>::size_table(){
        cout << "iii";
    }
    template <class T>
    void openhash<T>::print_table(){
        cout << "iii";
    }

    template <class T>
    openhash<T>::openhash(){

         vector<T> OAHashVector;

    }

    template <class T>
    openhash<T>::~openhash(){

    }


template < class T >
void menu(openhash<T> OAHash){
char option;




cout << "\t\t MENU \n"
     << "\t Press 'i' to insert an item to hashtable\n"
     << "\t Press 'd' to delete an item from hashtable\n"
     << "\t Press 'p' to print the hashtable\n"
     << "\t Press 'l' to look up an item in the hashtable\n"    
     << "\t Press 's' to display the size of the hashtable\n"
     << "\t Press 'q' to quit\n";

cin >> option;

switch(option){
    case 'i' : OAHash.insert_element(OAHash);
    break;
    case 'd' : OAHash.delete_element();
    break;
    case 'p' : OAHash.print_table();
    break;
    case 'l' : OAHash.lookup_element();
    break;
    case 's' : OAHash.size_table();
    break;
    case 'q' : cout << "hjil";
    break;
}


}

void selectTable(){



cout << "Please enter table type" << endl;
cin >> type;

if ( type == "int" ){
    openhash<int> OAHash;
    menu(OAHash);
} /*else if (type == "string"){
openhash<std::string> OAHash;
menu(OAHash);
} else if (type == "char"){
openhash<char> OAHash;
menu(OAHash);
} else if (type == "float"){
openhash<float> OAHash;
menu(OAHash);
} else if (type == "double"){
openhash<double> OAHash;
menu(OAHash);
}*/

}


int main(){

selectTable();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I'm having trouble"_ is way too vague. [Clarify by editing your question please!](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26769702/edit)

Comment: At which line actually? Highlight this.

Comment: I have made the line bold. The line is: OAHashVector.insert(addElement, hashvalue);

Comment: I still can't spot any declarations/definitions for that mysterious `OAHashVector`, `OAHash` classes. Did you simply miss to `#include` something else?

Comment: In addition to putting a small amount of effort into research in the future, please also work on creating minimal examples. For example, the text of your menu is entirely irrelevant. By doing this you may discover the problem on your own as you create the example anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `OAHashVector` in this constructor:

```
template <class T>
openhash<T>::openhash(){

     vector<T> OAHashVector;

}
```

It is a local variable and only valid in that scope. It would not be usable elsewhere. You want to either pass things as function parameters appropriately or declare it as a class member variable if that makes more sense.

I suggest reading [this tutorial on variable scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm), and also Google results for ["not declared in this scope"](https://www.google.com/search?q=was+not+declared+in+this+scope). You may wish to do a minimal amount of research before posting here in the future.